# MAMP, HTML, CSS, JS, PHP files on iPad

Tags: php, localhost, mamp

I want to know if it is possible to put my HTML, CSS, JS, PHP files, database and MAMP on an iPad and access them locally through the iPad's web browser?

The reason why I ask this question is because my client asked if he can run everything on the iPad instead of having to use a laptop + iPad for a booth display.

My initial advice to him is to use iPad's web browser to connect via network (IP address:8888) to access the files on the laptop(installed with MAMP).

Anyone have any other advice?

Comment: And your advice was a good one

Comment: @JustinIurman Thanks for confirmation.

Comment: idevices are essentially USELESS if you need filesystem access, or installing non-apple-approved apps. Of course, you could void the warranty and jailbreak the thing. If you want to do a demo system with a totally "native" stack, then go with at least an Android system, which does provide filesystem access and side-loading capabilities, or a Windows tablet like a Surface Pro, which is literally a windows PC in tablet format.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks for sharing. Is it possible to install MAMP on Android or Windows tablet?

Comment: mamp = mac amp. you want wamp for windows. as long as Win tablet isn't an RT device, it's just a regular PC in tablet format and you can install whatever you want. I have no idea if there's mysql or apache or php binaries for android.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks for explaining. I understand better now.

Answer (score 0):

No. MAMP is not available for iPad (and computers / interpreters are banned from the app store).